# ogr2ogr window closes after termination?

Tags: ogr2ogr, command-line

I'm using ogr2ogr for export from PostGIS to FileGDB. It works fine, but after termination the command window closes immediately.

Is there a way to keep it open and get some kind of message or report if the task was executed successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 7, you can activate `Open Command Window Here` as a context menu entry. On Windows XP, this can be added with the Windows XP PowerToys from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-xp-support-has-ended-47b944b8-f4d3-82f2-9acc-21c79ee6ef5e#2TC=powertoys). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378319/windows-explorer-command-prompt-here for other solutions.

Another way is to use the GDAL binaries from [gisinternals](https://web.archive.org/web/20141013002306/http://www.gisinternals.com:80/sdk/). You double-click on the `SDKshell.bat`, and the command line window will stay open until you close it manually. The OSGEO4W shell works similar. In both cases, the environment gets automatically set to the GDAL binaries, and will be reset after closing.

Third chance: put your commands into a bat file, and add a `pause` command in the last line. This will let the window open until you hit any key.